# JavaScript how to loop key value pairs inside a function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript.

I have 2 key and value pairs they are ids:

```
myselect->myoption
myselect2->myoption2
```

Code:

```
  function checkboxStatusChanges() {
    var multiselect = document.getElementById("myselect");
    var multiselectOption = multiselect.getElementsByTagName('option')[0];
  
    var values = [];
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById("myoption");
    var checkedCheckboxes = checkboxes.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  
    for (const item of checkedCheckboxes) {
      var checkboxValue = item.getAttribute('value');
      values.push(checkboxValue);
    }
  
    var dropdownValue = "Nothing is selected";
    if (values.length > 0) {
      dropdownValue = values.join(', ');
    }
  
    multiselectOption.innerText = dropdownValue;
  }
```

The code already used 1 of the pair values myselect->myoption document.getElementById("myselect") ,my question is ,how to code a loop inside the code ,so that both of the 2 pair values can be used in the code ?

Comment: `for (const [key, value] of [['myselect', 'myoption'], ['myselect2', 'myoption2']]) { console.log(key, value); }` is one way.

Comment: @Wyck Thank you very much for you reply ,can you post this as an detail answer ?Thanks!

Comment: select elements have direct properties that you should use rather than this kind of non conforming js code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array of objects to solve this. Define your pair value inside `object.selectId` and `object.optionId` and do forEach to apply the function for those objects like this:

```js
function checkboxStatusChanges() {
    let targetIds = [{
            "selectId": "myselect",
            "optionId": "myoption"
        },
        {
            "selectId": "myselect2",
            "optionId": "myoption2"
        }
    ];
    targetIds.forEach(function(targetId) {
        var multiselect = document.getElementById(targetId.selectId);
        var multiselectOption = multiselect.getElementsByTagName('option')[0];

        var values = [];
        var checkboxes = document.getElementById(targetId.optionId);
        var checkedCheckboxes = checkboxes.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');

        for (const item of checkedCheckboxes) {
            var checkboxValue = item.getAttribute('value');
            values.push(checkboxValue);
        }

        var dropdownValue = "Nothing is selected";
        if (values.length > 0) {
            dropdownValue = values.join(', ');
        }

        multiselectOption.innerText = dropdownValue;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir ,can you also help with this one,this is the last one of today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75991389/javascript-for-loop-inside-a-function-not-work

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this one :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76009630/javascript-to-to-change-input-type-date-format-and-value?noredirect=1#comment134057558_76009630

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that your function is **absolutely fine** as is, except that you want to **parameterize** `"myselect"` and `"myoption"` as `key` and `value`.  So, you can do that at the function level.  Parameterization is a fundamental feature of functions in JavaScript and, easy peasy:

```
 function checkboxStatusChanges(key, value) {
    var multiselect = document.getElementById(key);
    var multiselectOption = multiselect.getElementsByTagName('option')[0];
  
    var values = [];
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById(value);
    var checkedCheckboxes = checkboxes.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  
    for (const item of checkedCheckboxes) {
      var checkboxValue = item.getAttribute('value');
      values.push(checkboxValue);
    }
  
    var dropdownValue = "Nothing is selected";
    if (values.length > 0) {
      dropdownValue = values.join(', ');
    }
  
    multiselectOption.innerText = dropdownValue;
  }
```

Now you just need to call this function twice, once with each `key`, `value` pair.

In the simplest form you can now do:

```
checkboxStatusChanges('myselect', 'myoption');
checkboxStatusChanges('myselect2', 'myoption2');
```

If you need a single function that does both those things because it's an event handler or something, then that's also very easy to solve:

```
function allChanges() {
  checkboxStatusChanges('myselect', 'myoption');
  checkboxStatusChanges('myselect2', 'myoption2');
}
```

And now that we've gotten all that out of the way, if you really insist on doing so, you could use a loop:

```
const pairs = [
  ['myselect', 'myoption'],
  ['myselect2', 'myoption2']
];

for (const [key, value] of pairs) {
  checkboxStatusChanges(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Hi sir thank you so much for your reply ,can you help with this question too :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75991389/javascript-for-loop-inside-a-function-not-work?noredirect=1#comment134027397_75991389